# Unable to verify the displayed Label in Login Page

Tags: jasmine-node

Can any one help me on this scenario.

Scenario: When user try to login the application with invalid credentials then a alert message is displayed on page it self as "Invalid login credentials" and it gets disappear by itself.

Here I am unable to capture this message for verification.  I have tried as following:

```
msg = element(by.binding("errmsg"));
msg.tomatch('Invalid Login Credentials');
```

Here is the below code from where I have taken:

```
<div id="div_InvalidAccess" class="col-lg-8 span_new" ng-show="invalidAccess" style="display: none;">
    <label id="errMsg" class="ng-binding">Invalid Login Credentials</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Here is the below code from where I have taken :

<div id="div_InvalidAccess" class="col-lg-8 span_new" ng-show="invalidAccess" style="display: none;">
<label id="errMsg" class="ng-binding">Invalid Login Credentials</label>
                </div>

Comment: Edited question to show hidden code.